# Typescript adding unwanted string type to type alias property

Tags: typescript

I have the following code

```
type ValidateFn = (value: any) => boolean;

type ValidationSchema<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Array<ValidateFn> | ValidateFn | ValidationSchema<T[P]>
}

interface Person {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}

const obj: ValidationSchema<Person> = {
    'name': 'test' // <-- problem is here
}
```

Typescript compiler is saying that the fields of ValidationSchema are either

```
string | ValidateFn | ValidateFn[]
```

Where did the `string` come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` where `T` is some type parameter are called *homomorphic*, as introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447) (which calls them *isomorphic*).  In that pull request, it says

> when a primitive type is substituted for `T` in an isomorphic mapped type, we simply produce that primitive type.

If a primitive type like `string` goes in, the same primitive type comes out:

```
type SomeHomomorphicMappedType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Date };
type MappedString = SomeHomomorphicMappedType<string>; // string
```

---

Since `ValidationSchema` is a homomorphic recursive mapped type, when it recurses down into the `name` and `age` properties of `Person`, it gets applied as `ValidationSchema<string | undefined>` for `name` and `ValidationSchema<number | undefined>` for age.  Primitive in, primitive out:

```
type VSP = ValidationSchema<Person>
/* type VSP = {
    name?: string | ValidateFn | ValidateFn[] | undefined;
    age?: number | ValidateFn | ValidateFn[] | undefined;
} */
```

So, that explains it.

---

If you want some other behavior you might want to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to do something different when `T extends object` vs when it doesn't.  Maybe like this:

```
type ValidationSchemaMaybe<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Array<ValidateFn> | ValidateFn | (
    T[P] extends object ? ValidationSchemaMaybe<T[P]> : never
  );
}

type VSPMaybe = ValidationSchemaMaybe<Person>
/* type VSPMaybe = {
    name?: ValidateFn | ValidateFn[] | undefined;
    age?: ValidateFn | ValidateFn[] | undefined;
} */
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZQPYFsYAlVYE5QBYCWAxgLICGUsAJgCrQwA8NAfHALxwDecA2gNJwCAOzgBrGBCQAzODQC6ALjgARMmHgBfANyhIsOOUowqCMNmEBzdolQYsKJLkKkK1OrAYBnM5eZa4APQBcN7mQhagQQGguvRwAGpkADYEVGowAGIiHAAUAG7JAK4wSmRCEACU7KwARkhISTBlOiCx+okpaWAESEIIRHgwKGRMrBzcoHC8AAqCIuKSMvJKAILY2GQQDB2p6VmsAD4JybvqWXBHO109fQNDIzQ803LMoBoxIMLq2FJkRPDTGDYTy9LiTOBCMhoAD8SlClhaUzIFhgsIhhRQNSBLXerXAcXiCFmHCuahu-UGwwYgOBvVeIACACo4Hp4ITiWCQFMppCYXCfOELsdOnsRJcTl1MkIeHIhYUhFQYFJhMZEdzkailEIMVjsELSWcxcLTlKZXKFUqVVQcXBGdE8azjddehT7uQIFjRtZOOCnnMxBJpLJFHA1hstgapYcnaKhTlwVNHs84DAAB7qBWeOBIGoAKxgRDAcGhMe6Lruw3dnqTLzgWpgeSB4IqOI+jvZVfgJIlZPLlLInepQJBQnpTJZBKJne9CYhUM1pal+p7hrNR3liuVQlVs41aMj53FItXsvXFq3O5AGltASAA)